# rake aborted by NotImplementedError when db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rake

I get NotImplementedError when I run `rake db:create --trace`, and this is full trace of the command.

```
rake db:create --trace
rake aborted!
NotImplementedError
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railroady-1.1.1/tasks/railroady.rake:34:in `sed'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railroady-1.1.1/tasks/railroady.rake:47:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:196:in `in_namespace'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:104:in `namespace'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railroady-1.1.1/tasks/railroady.rake:41:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railroady-1.1.1/lib/railroady/railtie.rb:8:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `instance_exec'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `run_tasks_blocks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:243:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:17:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:17:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:243:in `run_tasks_blocks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:446:in `load_tasks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
C:/Users/ironsand/dev/tangocho/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

To fix the error I reinstall `rake` by `gem uninstall rake`, `gem install rake`.

And I also tried with `rake.bat`.

I tried same thing also with `Railsinstaller3.0(Ruby2.0.0)`.

But all try didn't work.

If I create a new rails project, then `rake db:create` works properly.

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Have you run bundle install?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I had a error indicate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I have bad news. The project you are trying to run depends on railroady gem, which heavily depends on system sed command. This command is not available on windows, so I'm afraid there won't be any easy solutions.

There are number of tools which tries to add sed command to windows, you can always try installing one of them (Google 'sed windows') and changing the gem so it knows how to call it (with what options etc).

However the best solution would be to say goodbye to windows and move to linux. With enough googling skills you will never look back.